# Importing json file to firebase manually

Tags: json, firebase

I have a json file. when i am trying import it to firebase i am getting error showing in the image below.

[image]

i am adding my json structure here

```
{
  "C": [
    {
        "Options" : {
          "a" : "LowerCase letter",
          "b" : "UpperCase letter",
          "c" : "CamelCase letter",
          "d" : "None of the mentioned"
        },
        "Question" : "All keywords in C are in ____________",
        "answer_indexanswer_index" : "a",
        "id" : 1
      },
      {
        "Options" : {
          "a" : "LowerCase letter",
          "b" : "UpperCase letter",
          "c" : "CamelCase letter",
          "d" : "None of the mentioned"
        },
        "Question" : "All keywords in C are in ____________",
        "answer_indexanswer_index" : "a",
        "id" : 1
      }
  ]
}
```

Comment: i have added my json structure in the question

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the shared, JSON file. Are you sure you are using this structure? I have uploaded it successfully.

Comment: Agree with @AlexMamo - copy and pasted the structure into a text file and it imported correctly into Firebase. Perhaps there's something else in the file?